# Грамотное объяснение callback-функций для новичков

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

Помогите разобраться с реализацией callback-функции. Как я понял, она служит для асинхронного выполнения кода. Но как это делается я до конца не понял. Был бы рад увидеть объяснение на рабочем коде, а не на коде примере, который не несет смысла в рабочем проекте.
Я имел в виду вот такую разницу.

```
function some_function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    var my_number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (arg1 - arg2) + arg2);
    callback(my_number);
}
some_function(5, 15, function (num) {
    console.log("callback called! " + num);
});
```

И

```
function some_function2(url, callback) {
    var httpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new
        ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            callback.call(httpRequest.responseXML);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
}
some_function2("text.xml", function () {
    console.log(this);
});
console.log("1");
```

Comment: как ты определил, что код в примере не несет смысла?

Comment: Сам то пример имеет смыл. Только я хотел увидеть вариант, который часто используется в работе. Чтобы лучше понять как применяют данную функцию

Comment: честно говоря, я не вижу разницы в этих двух примерах

Comment: Знаете вы правы, смотря для чего применять. Но я до конца не понимаю как callback функция работает. Поэтому и вопрос возможно некорректный. Как я понял есть функция в параметре которой есть другая функция. При выполнении кода внутри 1 функции результат мы заносим в параметр 2 функции. А затем мы вызываем вторую функцию с нужным нам кодом, которая уже имеет параметр. так и получается асинхронное выполнение кода

Comment: почти так: суть в том, что функция **сама** определяет когда и с какими параметрами вызывать функцию callback. И асинхронность тут, в принципе не причем. например, метод `forEach` вполне синхронный, но принимающий callback

Comment: @Grundy +1 - асинхронность ни при чем, -1 - за слово "себе"

Comment: @Igor, убрал _себе_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy оформите как ответ?

Comment: @PashaPash, мне казалось тут прям дубликат подходит хорошо, не понимаю почему решили переоткрыть

Comment: @Grundy тот вопрос общий ("что такое callback"), этот - более специфический - какой смысл в callback-ах без асинхронности.

Comment: @Grundy т.е. если взять ответ от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666819/ - он никак на конкретный вопрос топикастера (почему именно callback) не ответит

Comment: @PashaPash, а там же первый пример с filter как раз без асинхронности, мой комментарий по сути выжимка из первого пункта того ответа. У меня что-то очень похожий ответ выходит просто :-)